# List Index Out of Range error - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames. df1 looks like -

```
MovieName    Actors
lights out   Maria Bello
legend       Tom Hardy*Emily Browning*Christopher Eccleston*David Thewlis
```

df2 looks like -

```
ActorName    Gender
Tom          male
Emily        female
Christopher  male
```

I want to add two columns in df1 'female_actors' and 'male_actors' which contains the count of female and male actors in that particular movie respectively. Whether an actor is male or female is done based on df2.

Here is what I am doing -

```
def func(actors, gender):
    actors = [act.split()[0] for act in actors.split('*')]      
    n_gender = df2.Gender[df2.Gender==gender][df2.ActorName.isin(actors)].count()
    return n_gender

df1['male_actors'] = df1.Actors.apply(lambda x: func(x, 'male'))
df1['female_actors'] = df1.Actors.apply(lambda x: func(x, 'female'))
```

**This code gives me list index out of range error.**

Please note that -

If particular name isn't present in gender.csv, don't count it in the total.
If there is just one actor in a movie, and it isn't present in gender.csv, then it's count should be zero.

Result should be -

```
MovieName    Actors      male_actors    female_actors
lights out   Maria Bello    0              0
legend       Tom Hardy*Emily Browning*Christopher Eccleston*David Thewlis    2    1
```

Feel free to suggest some other approach.

Comment: Only place in your code where a list is being indexed is at `act.split()[0]`, is it possible that in some cases the `Actors` field is empty?

Comment: @sirfz I have removed all empty rows. It runs now. But what do you think is the problem that it only identifies a max count of 1, even when there are like  20 actors mentioned. Does it automatically read only a certain length of row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
df1['Male'] = df1.Actors.apply(lambda x: len(pd.concat( [df2[(df2.ActorName == name) & (df2.Gender == 'male')] for name in x.split('*')] )))
df1['Female'] = df1.Actors.apply(lambda x: len(pd.concat( [df2[(df2.ActorName == name) & (df2.Gender == 'female')] for name in x.split('*')] )))
```

Comment: This will need editing if your actor names in `df2` are e.g. 'Tom' - as is written - instead of 'Tom Hardy'. If you only have the first names you could replace `(df2.ActorName == name)` with `(df2.ActorName == name.split()[0])`

Comment: I am doing the same process for other fields like Directors, Writers etc, and I get list index out of range error. Can u suggest a possible solution to that?

Comment: From what I can tell this would only happen if you included the `(df2.ActorName == name.split()[0])` modification I suggested, did you add that? Try adding `if name` inside the list comprehension e.g. `[df2[(df2.ActorName == name.split()[0]) & (df2.Gender == 'female')] for name in x.split('*') if name]`

Comment: This will cause an issue if there are are no names (0 actors) in which case you should make sure to throw an empty dataframe into the `pd.concat` function. Here is the ugly beast I have in mind: `pd.concat( [pd.DataFrame()] + [df2[(df2.ActorName == name.split()[0]) & (df2.Gender == 'female')] for name in x.split('*') if name])`

Answer (score 1):

using `str` and `join`

```
d2 = df2.set_index('ActorName')
d1 = df1.set_index('MovieName')
```

***method 1***
`split`

```
d1.join(d1.Actors.str.split('*', expand=True).stack() \
    .str.split(expand=True)[0].map(d2.Gender) \
    .groupby(level='MovieName') \
    .value_counts().unstack()).fillna(0).reset_index()
```

***method 2***
`extractall`

```
d1.join(d1.Actors.str.extractall('((?P<first>[^*]+)\s+(?P<last>[^*]+))') \
    ['first'].map(d2.Gender).groupby(level='MovieName') \
    .value_counts().unstack()).fillna(0).reset_index()
```

[image]